# How to make images overlay card borders in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When you use cards, the whole card has a border. It creates a not so nice looking pixel offset at the image's bottom corners. It looks like the image is one pixel too far to the left.

I've tried giving the image negative margins and left and right positioning, but it doesnt work.

Is there any best practice or elegant way of making the image overlap the border of the card?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pt-5 px-5">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x180/095865/000000">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h2 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p class="card-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x180/095865/000000">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h2 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p class="card-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4o9wd28/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
.card-img-top {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/5psLgxe2/3/

Comment: ha thats also the solution i came up with! i didnt know `calc` was a thing again :)

Answer (score 1):

You could unset the `.card`'s border class and give the border to the `.card-body`'s class instead.

```css
.card { border: unset !important; }
.card-body { border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125); border-radius: 0 0 .25rem .25rem; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pt-5 px-5">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x180/095865/000000">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h2 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p class="card-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x180/095865/000000">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h2 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p class="card-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```